# Pushing only one item instead of pushing number of the objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to push a new item into the favlist, I have used a for loop to check whether the item already exists in the favlist.

However, instead of pushing the new item once, repeated number of new item is pushed instead.

What's the best way of fixing this?

Thanks in advance!

---

```
$scope.favlist = JSON.parse($window.localStorage.getItem("favlist"));
    console.log($scope.favlist);

    $scope.toggleStar = function(item) {
      item.star = !item.star;
      console.log(item); //object


      var favlistcontent = $window.localStorage.getItem("favlist");
        console.log(favlistcontent); //string

        if(typeof favlistcontent !== 'string'){
         $scope.favlist = [];
         $window.localStorage.setItem("favlist",JSON.stringify($scope.favlist));
       }
       $scope.favlist = JSON.parse($window.localStorage.getItem("favlist"));
      console.log($scope.favlist); //object
      console.log($scope.favlist.length);

      console.log(angular.equals($scope.favlist[0],item)); //true
      for(i=0; i<$scope.favlist.length; i++){
        if(angular.equals($scope.favlist[i],item)){
          console.log("item already exists");


       }
       else {
        $scope.favlist.push(item);
        $window.localStorage.setItem("favlist",JSON.stringify($scope.favlist));
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us the value of favlist and item?

Comment: at the moment is 2, and item is one Object only! (I have added extra bit of code)

Answer (score 2):

You need to break the loop once an equal item is found, else it's going to continue and add the item when an unequal item is checked.

```
var duplicate = false;


for (i = 0; i < $scope.favlist.length; i++) {
    if (angular.equals($scope.favlist[i], item)) {
        console.log("item already exists");
        //break loop here
        duplicate = true;
        break;
    }

}

if (!duplicate){
    $scope.favlist.push(item);
    $window.localStorage.setItem("favlist", JSON.stringify($scope.favlist));
}
```

Comment: Darn it :D I was just going to answer the same thing! You beat me to it. Upvoting this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to fix this is to use:

```js
  if($scope.favlist.indexOf(item)==-1){
    // item is no duplicate
    $scope.favlist.push(item);
    $window.localStorage.setItem("favlist", JSON.stringify($scope.favlist));
  }
```

The check looks much simpler.
In a good Browser the indexOf function will be always faster then "manual" looping.

See this Benchmark: https://jsperf.com/js-for-loop-vs-array-indexof/10